# InnoDB - drawbacks of using composite primary key to cluster rows, instead of secondary indexes?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Taking a forum post as an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE Post (
    threadId INT,
    order INT,
    message VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (threadId, order)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

InnoDB physically orders rows by primary keys. In this case, answers to a question could be looked up by `questionId`, and they would be in the same order on disk so would require less disk seeking.

Are there any significant drawbacks to using this approach for fast read access?

I am primarily concerned with database size and read throughput, less so with write throughput. The table size is expected to be 150gb at max. I have no other indexes on the table. Records are bulk-inserted, usually by primary key. My queries all look up records by primary key.

Comment: "InnoDB physically orders rows by primary keys": I doubt it. Much too difficult after deletions and insertions. But it should intrinsically return rows in that order if you don't specify another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your queries typically look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Post
  WHERE threadID = '1'
  ORDER BY `order`
```

If you don't mind the difficulty in updating the records if the order changes, then your design is fine.

Adding order to the primary key forces the order values to be unique (per thread ID). So, when you want to reorder something, you can't temporarily have duplicate numbers. Instead, you have to come up with some scheme to update the order of the records that won't create duplicates.

For even better performance, reduce the size of the `message` column.

To avoid impacting write performance, insert the records in order.

**Other Considerations**

At the cost of write performance and storage, you could add a *covering index*. Assuming you've configured InnoDB to use enough memory and your system has enough available, MySQL can use the covering index to serve the whole query result up from RAM.

Also, you can use a *memory table* for read performance at the cost of write performance.